# Haskell data, custom string values

Tags: haskell, sdk, http-conduit

I am writing a [Haskell SDK](https://github.com/datarank/datarank-haskell), I have everything working however I'm wanting to introduce stronger types to my search filters (url parameters).

A sample call looks like:

```
-- list first 3 positive comments mentioned by females
comments "tide-pods" [("limit", "3"),("sentiment", "positive"),("gender", "female")] config
```

While this isn't too horrible for me, I would really like to be able to pass in something like:

```
comments "tide-pods" [("limit", "3"),(Sentiment, Positive),(Gender, Male)] config
```

Or something similar.

In DataRank.hs you can see my url parameter type `type QueryParameter = (String, String)`, as well as the code to convert the arguments for http-conduit `convertParameters :: [QueryParameter] -> [(ByteString, Maybe ByteString)]`

I have been experimenting with data/types, for example:

```
data Gender = Male | Female | Any 
-- desired values of above data types
-- Male = "male"
-- Female = "female"
-- Any = "male,female"
```

The api also needs to remain flexible enough for any arbitrary String key, String values because I would like the SDK to keep the ability to supply new filters without depending on a SDK update. For the curious, A list of the search filters to-date are in a recently built [Java SDK](https://github.com/datarank/datarank-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/datarank/api/request/filters)

I was having problems finding a good way to provide the search interface in Haskell. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `data FilterKey = Sentiment SentimentValue | Gender GenderValue | Arbitrary String String`, then you could do `comments "tide-pods" [Arbitrary "limit" "3", Sentiment Positive, Gender Male] config`

Comment: You could have a `comments :: String -> [FilterKey] -> Config -> Result` and `commentsRaw :: String -> [(String, String)] -> Config -> Result`, where `comments` calls `commentsRaw`, and just write a function `filterKeyToPair :: FilterKey -> (String, String)`.  That would be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! Now, when I'm iterating over my list of parameters to pass to http-conduit, how do I get the desired values (notably the ANY = "male,female"? Do I just do a guard and return the correct String?

Comment: You could do something like [this](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/f3ea4a4b19fb2bf005ea) if you wanted to keep it simple for now.

Comment: I solved this problem by creating a data type for each endpoint's options. Then I used lenses to cleanly set particular options. Check out my library for examples: https://github.com/tfausak/strive#update-current-athlete.

Comment: Thanks for the links guys! Will check them out and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @KennyCason Check out [this](https://gist.github.com/bheklilr/6ab4074cadc86ddf188b) for a more complicated API that is arguably nicer.  It allows users of your API to extend it pretty easily with their own custom types, so you could even split this into a base API then packages that implement the filters themselves, or at least split it into different modules.

Comment: The examples have helped tremendously! @bheklilr You should take the samples from those links and create an answer :) Particularly the first link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to keep it simple but unsafe is to just use a basic ADT with an `Arbitrary` field that takes a `String` key and value:

```
data FilterKey
    = Arbitrary String String
    | Sentiment Sentiment
    | Gender Gender
    deriving (Eq, Show)

data Sentiment
    = Positive
    | Negative
    | Neutral
    deriving (Eq, Show, Bounded, Enum)

data Gender
    = Male
    | Female
    | Any
    deriving (Eq, Show, Bounded, Enum)
```

Then you need a function to convert a `FilterKey` to your API's base `(String, String)` filter type

```
filterKeyToPair :: FilterKey -> (String, String)
filterKeyToPair (Arbitrary key val) = (key, val)
filterKeyToPair (Sentiment sentiment) = ("sentiment", showSentiment sentiment)
filterKeyToPair (Gender gender) = ("gender", showGender gender)

showSentiment :: Sentiment -> String
showSentiment s = case s of
    Positive -> "positive"
    Negative -> "negative"
    Neutral  -> "neutral"

showGender :: Gender -> String
showGender g = case g of
    Male   -> "male"
    Female -> "female"
    Any    -> "male,female"
```

And finally you can just wrap your base API's `comments` function so that the filters parameter is more typesafe, and it's converted to the `(String, String)` form internally to send the request

```
comments :: String -> [FilterKey] -> Config -> Result
comments name filters conf = do
    let filterPairs = map filterKeyToPair filters
    commentsRaw name filterPairs conf
```

This will work quite well and is fairly easy to use:

```
comments "tide-pods" [Arbitrary "limits" "3", Sentiment Positive, Gender Female] config
```

But it isn't very extensible.  If a user of your library wants to extend it to add a `Limit Int` field, they would have to write it as

```
data Limit = Limit Int

limitToFilterKey :: Limit -> FilterKey
limitToFilterKey (Limit l) = Arbitrary "limit" (show l)
```

And it would instead look like

```
[limitToFilterKey (Limit 3), Sentiment Positive, Gender Female]
```

which isn't particularly nice, especially if they're trying to add a lot of different fields and types.  A complex but extensible solution would be to have a single `Filter` type, and actually for simplicity have it capable of representing a single filter or a list of filters (try implementing it where `Filter = Filter [(String, String)]`, it's a bit harder to do cleanly):

```
import Data.Monoid hiding (Any)

-- Set up the filter part of the API

data Filter
    = Filter (String, String)
    | Filters [(String, String)]
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Monoid Filter where
    mempty = Filters []
    (Filter   f) `mappend` (Filter  g)  = Filters [f, g]
    (Filter   f) `mappend` (Filters gs) = Filters (f : gs)
    (Filters fs) `mappend` (Filter  g)  = Filters (fs ++ [g])
    (Filters fs) `mappend` (Filters gs) = Filters (fs ++ gs)
```

Then have a class to represent the conversion to a `Filter` (much like `Data.Aeson.ToJSON`):

```
class FilterKey kv where
    keyToString :: kv -> String
    valToString :: kv -> String
    toFilter :: kv -> Filter
    toFilter kv = Filter (keyToString kv, valToString kv)
```

The instance for `Filter` is quite simple

```
instance FilterKey Filter where
    -- Unsafe because it doesn't match the Fitlers contructor
    -- but I never said this was a fully fleshed out API
    keyToString (Filter (k, _)) = k
    valToString (Filter (_, v)) = v
    toFilter = id
```

A quick trick you can do here to easily combine values of this type is

```
-- Same fixity as <>
infixr 6 &
(&) :: (FilterKey kv1, FilterKey kv2) => kv1 -> kv2 -> Filter
kv1 & kv2 = toFilter kv1 <> toFilter kv2
```

Then you can write instances of the `FilterKey` class that work with:

```
data Arbitrary = Arbitrary String String deriving (Eq, Show)

infixr 7 .=
(.=) :: String -> String -> Arbitrary
(.=) = Arbitrary

instance FilterKey Arbitrary where
    keyToString (Arbitrary k _) = k
    valToString (Arbitrary _ v) = v

data Sentiment
    = Positive
    | Negative
    | Neutral
    deriving (Eq, Show, Bounded, Enum)

instance FilterKey Sentiment where
    keyToString _        = "sentiment"
    valToString Positive = "positive"
    valToString Negative = "negative"
    valToString Neutral  = "neutral"

data Gender
    = Male
    | Female
    | Any
    deriving (Eq, Show, Bounded, Enum)

instance FilterKey Gender where
    keyToString _      = "gender"
    valToString Male   = "male"
    valToString Female = "female"
    valToString Any    = "male,female"
```

Add a bit of sugar:

```
data Is = Is

is :: Is
is = Is

sentiment :: Is -> Sentiment -> Sentiment
sentiment _ = id

gender :: Is -> Gender -> Gender
gender _ = id
```

And you can write queries like

```
example
    = comments "tide-pods" config
    $ "limit" .= "3"
    & sentiment is Positive
    & gender is Any
```

This API can still be safe if you don't export the constructors to `Filter` and if you don't export `toFilter`.  I left that as a method on the typeclass simply so that `Filter` can override it with `id` for efficiency.  Then a user of your library simply does

```
data Limit
    = Limit Int
    deriving (Eq, Show)

instance FilterKey Limit where
    keyToString _ = "limit"
    valToString (Limit l) = show l
```

If they wanted to keep the `is` style they could use

```
limit :: Is -> Int -> Limit
limit _ = Limit
```

And write something like

```
example
    = comments "foo" config
    $ limit is 3
    & sentiment is Positive
    & gender is Female
```

But that is shown here simply as an example of one way you can make EDSLs in Haskell look very readable.